# Creating a clickable 3d rendering of a webpage inside a 3D Scene

Tags: html, three.js

I'm trying to understand how to render a webpage inside a 3d Scene usign Three.js, but al the examples I can find end up rendering something that you can't click. 
I've seen videos from quite a few years ago that display the rendered pages being clickable, but that code no longer works.
Is this no longer possible? All I've gotten so far, is that I will be needing to create a CSS3DObject object, but any attempt at catching click events on it (or it's children) yields no results.

Any help / guidance will be appreciated.

*Edit: Adding simple code I've tried*

```
 function createCssObject(w, h, position, rotation, url) {

var html = [

  '<div style="width:' + w + 'px; height:' + h + 'px;">',
  '<iframe src="' + url + '" width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '">',
  '</iframe>',
  '</div>'

].join('\n');

var div = document.createElement('div');

$(div).html(html);

var cssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject(div);

cssObject.position.x = position.x;
cssObject.position.y = position.y;
cssObject.position.z = position.z;

cssObject.rotation.x = rotation.x;
cssObject.rotation.y = rotation.y;
cssObject.rotation.z = rotation.z;
cssObject.element.onclick = function() {
    console.log("element clicked!");
}

return cssObject;
```

**Update 2: working jsfiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/edkLLjcm/4/

Comment: _" any attempt at catching click events on it (or it's children) yields no results"_ Any live code examples of what you've tried?

Comment: added the code I've tried, honestly, nothing much, just things I've picked up from tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're mixing in OrbitControls or TrackballControls, you are going to have to do some clever enabling and disabling them, at the point that you want your web pages to become interactable. OrbitControls/TrackballControls don't really have a way of knowing that certain events are intended to be eaten by your dom elements.

One option is to toggle them based on a key handler, and have a key that toggles the mouse cursor in and out. Once you toggle them off, you will also need to make sure your app itself isn't eating the relevant events, by making sure you aren't calling event.preventDefault in your handlers, and that you are returning the correct boolean value from the handlers you do have to indicate that they should continue "bubbling". I don't remember the exact semantics and it is fiddly to get right, but you can get it to work.

edit:

I think the problem was that you are adding the canvas as a child of the  cssRenderers domElement.

I changed it to:

```
document.body.appendChild(cssRenderer.domElement);
document.body.appendChild(glRenderer.domElement);
//cssRenderer.domElement.appendChild(glRenderer.domElement);
```

and it seems to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/edkLLjcm/8/

Comment: Thanks for  the reponse, I've added a working fiddle so you know what I'm doing. I've removed the controls import and code, in order to take that out of the equation, and still, I get no interaction with the webpages.

Comment: I think the problem was that you are adding the canvas as a child of the  cssRenderers domElement.

I updated my answer above.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! that'll do! Awesome!